# Unexpect result from boost posix_time

Tags: c++, boost

When I run this in my ubuntu, I get the bottom result. What could go wrong with this? There is no way the result year is 1970, and see when I do the reconvert the `ms` back, the result aren't the same. But when I run it at http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/ it was fine.

```cpp
#include <boost/date_time/gregorian/gregorian.hpp>
#include <boost/date_time/posix_time/posix_time.hpp>

#include <string>
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
    using namespace boost::posix_time;
    ptime time_t_epoch(boost::gregorian::date(1970,1,1));

    auto ms = (boost::posix_time::microsec_clock::local_time() - time_t_epoch).total_microseconds();
    std::cout << "ms: " << ms << std::endl;
     std::cout << "ms: " << boost::posix_time::microseconds(ms).total_microseconds() << std::endl;
    ptime newTime = time_t_epoch + boost::posix_time::microseconds(ms);
    std::cout << boost::posix_time::to_iso_string(time_t_epoch) << std::endl;
    std::cout << boost::posix_time::to_iso_string(newTime) << std::endl;
    std::stringstream ss;
    ss << newTime;
    std::cout <<  ss.str()<< std::endl;
}
```

Result:

```
ms: 1424976249761218

ms: 4576956085582

19700101T000000

19700222T232236.085582

1970-Feb-22 23:22:36.085582
```

Machine environment = Ubuntu 12 + cmake 2.8.7 + boost 1.48.0.2

Comment: If you add 4576956085582 microseconds to 1970/01/01 then it's correct, that's 1970-Feb-22... 1424976249761218 microseconds from 1970/01/01 is also 2015/02/26 so ms sounds good. The question is why boost::posix_time::microseconds(ms).total_microseconds() != ms

Comment: And it might be related to this bug https://svn.boost.org/trac/boost/ticket/3487 I'm (negatively) amazed that it can remain opened for so long

Comment: put it to the answer please

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1970/01/01 + 4576956085582 microseconds -> 1970-Feb-22 is correct

1970/01/01 + 1424976249761218 microseconds -> 2015-Feb-26 so `ms` is presumably correct

What is not correct is that

```
boost::posix_time::microseconds(ms).total_microseconds() != ms
```

It might be related to this bug https://svn.boost.org/trac/boost/ticket/3487 though I'm not sure.